# Behaviour of base class method when hiding/overloading helper methods in inherited class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, method-hiding, overriding

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return GetName();
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public new string GetName()
    {
        return "Bar";
    }
}


new Foo().Test(); // Foo

new Bar().Test(); // also Foo
```

I was trying to create a "wrapper" for `Foo` so that I could unit test the behaviour of `Test()` when `GetName()` produces unexpected values. I cannot directly influence the behaviour of `GetName()` in `Foo` as it is dependent on ASP.NET pipeline events.

I was hoping

`new Bar().Test();`

would return "Bar", but obviously I have misunderstood the inheritance model.

Is there any way of achieving what I need?

Comment: Do you have access to `Foo`? Can you make `Foo`.`GetName`() virtual and override it in `Bar`?

Comment: @Steve yes I could do that, but the behaviour seemed the same when I tried it. And it is obviously preferable to not change `Foo` purely for the purpose of getting a test to work.

Comment: @ShellShock has put this as an answer now - it should behave as you want. Changing it "purely to get a test to work" is one way of looking at it, changing it 'to be more testable' is a more positive slant :)

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet actually, you should verify [whether it should be hidden or overridden](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rakeshrajan/archive/2005/05/01/45188.aspx) - possibly the latter is the case anyway (without regard to the tests)?

Comment: @SteveWilkes yes that does appears to work - weird I tried that previously and thought that the result was the same, I must have made a mistake. Do you believe that using a wrapper class like this is an acceptable/valid testing technique then? It feels a bit hacky to me but I couldn't come up with any alternative in this case. Have you seen this used elsewhere?

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly valid, yeah - it's how mocks are created for concrete types and how the Entity Framework performs lazy-loading to name two examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetName needs to be virtual in your Foo and overridden in your Bar class. Like this:

```
public class Foo 
{
     public string Test()     
     {         
         return GetName();
     }

     public virtual string GetName()
     {
         return "Foo";
     }
}

public class Bar : Foo 
{
     public override string GetName()
     {
         return "Bar";
     }
}
```

Edit: but I now see from your new comment that changing Foo might not be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it does appear to work. I don't really get why using `new` doesn't work the same way though?